# How can I communicate across a VPN trust boundary on my home network?

Tags: vpn, routing

I have a primary network that is connected directly to my modem. Primary gateway: `192.168.0.1`.

From my primary router, I have another router connected. It has an IP address of `192.168.0.100` on the primary network but also has its own DHCP server enabled.

Secondary gateway: `192.168.1.1`.

My computers are connected to the primary gateway. I have my TVs and NAS connected to my secondary gateway.

Occasionally (not often), I need to my computers to communicate with the NAS in order to transfer some files.

How can I get from `192.168.0.x` to `192.168.1.x`?

Some additional information.
The secondary gateway is used for a VPN. So that all connections on that go through a VPN which is installed on the router. I want the traffic on my primary network to go through without a VPN and the traffic on the secondary network to go through the VPN.

Answer (score -1):

*(Step 3 from https://www.techwalla.com/articles/how-to-connect-computers-that-are-on-2-different-subnets)*

Enable a routing protocol in each subnet's router. Options include Routing Information Protocol (RIP), Open Shortest Path First (OSPF) or, on Cisco-based switches, Interior Gateway Routing Protocol (IGRP).